# How can I download text files from firebase storage that are not in ASCII numbers, but are converted into strings?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I have uploaded a string to Firebase storage (e.g. 'test2') as a raw string, using the following code:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`signupsData/${titleKey}.txt`);
console.log(signups.toString());
storageRef.putString(signups.toString()).then(() => storageRef.getDownloadURL()).then((url) => console.log(url));
```

(where signups.toString() === 'test2')

However, when clicking on the provided download url to retrieve the uploaded .txt file, the text displayed is in ASCII, i.e. instead of seeing 'test2', the text displayed is '116,101,115,116,50'.

Is there any way to download the file such that the ASCII is converted to text already (such that I see 'test2' instead of the above numbers)?

Comment: You don't explicitly say it, but I assume `test2` is printing in the console... and I doubt my recommendation will fix it, since your code already follows [the matching Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string)... but try forcing the `text/plain` type `.putString(signups.toString(), 'text/plain')` I doubt Firebase will like that syntax, and will probably error out... Try the way shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938969/angular-2-firebase-storage-putstring-method-support-metadata next.